# don't want to sort but want null values last

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to order by id asc, date asc, but in the case where there is a NULL I want those values
last.  So in the example below I really want to 1. order by id, 2. order by date asc where value is not null, and then 3) order by date asc, listing the rows with a value of NULL last.

```
id  date       value
A12 6/21/2012  125
A12 6/15/2012  NULL
B11 5/28/2011  100
C12 4/23/2012  168
```

How can I order the value column such that NULL values are last, without sorting the non-null values?

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. You say you want to put the NULL values last without sorting them, but you also say you want to order by `date ASC` which would sort the NULL values. So which is it?

Comment: Maybe this helps (although it did not work for me)  select * where value is not null order by id ASC, date ASC UNION select * where value is null order by id ASC, date ASC;  This would give all rows with a non-null in value sorted by date and then all rows with null in value also sorted by date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, date, value
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id, (CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), date
```

Comment: I tried this but not only will it move the nulls to the bottom but it will sort the value column

Comment: +1, I think you need to juggle the order by a bit: `id, case..., date`. But other wise good.

Comment: @Barry - it should not sort the value column. The order by clause was slightly out out of order. Just move the id to the front of the order by.

Comment: Thank you both!  @dbenham: your last comment got me to try again and this time with success.

Comment: @dbenham Ah, I misunderstood his requirements. I thought he wanted ALL `null`s to be at the bottom, and THEN sorted by `id`. But yes, easy to fix -- thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UNION` operator to attach the NULL values to the bottom of the result set after you have sorted the non-null ones:

```
SELECT id, date, value
FROM tbl
WHERE value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id, date

UNION ALL

SELECT id, date, value
FROM tbl
WHERE value IS NULL
ORDER BY id, date
```

Comment: I'm using sybase; I get an error when I use the order by in the first select.

Comment: I believe more than just sybase will reject that syntax. Also as a general rule, you should never rely on the order of results unless there is an explicit order by clause for the final result.